# Is it possible to do research in physics provided I won't be doing physics as full time major but rather a part time major

Tags: research-undergraduate, physics

I am currently a highschool student who is going to graduate senior year(12th grade as we call it here) this March(2024) and I am interested in persuing physics as major but due to circumstances and parental pressure I would be doing engineering in computer science (unfortunately,for me it's not my great interest).

Since I don't want to leave my interest for physics,I wish to persue it in distance mode(pretty much part time) and once I complete my engineering I would  enroll in PhD program(I know it's a lot to dream but I personally think I can make it..and I will make it somehow).

I had many dreams of how I would do research during my undergraduate years(which Every aspiring physics graduate has) and now I wonder,if I would be able to manage time with my dual majors..can I still do research provided I am not a full time student?

Comment: What do you see _physics research_ as an undergraduate being?

Comment: This is both off topic and depends too much on where you study and what the options are there. I'd guess it would be pretty difficult to manage and you might need to defer that goal until later.

Comment: My understanding of Undergraduate physics research is like giving mathematical modelling for complex non linear systems(there are hundred and arguably thousands of topics but non linear dynamics are something that particularly interest me at the moment). And honestly I don't see how this is offtopic since I really don't happen to have any approachable person in academia,this should be the perfect spot to do so;but I agree on the part that information is inadequate.

Comment: Your major does not define your whole academic life and research. You can definitely do research in physics as a computer scientist, specially in heavily computational fields such as non-linear dynamics. In my opinion the most interesting researches are in multidisciplinary fields. Nowadays you have people developing physics-based neural networks for example. This is coming from a computational Physicist working on ML/AI/Biostatistics.

Comment: Thanks doc.. I'll think about it

Comment: You could always double major in engineering and physics; my university has a special dual-enrollment option for this. Physics research is probably not what you expect it to be. I would recommend doing really well in physics courses, develop good relationships with these professors, and ask them for advice on doing research, or about their research specifically.

Comment: Ok,will work on it.